# Class anonymous class derived from HttpClientConfigCallback() must be declared abstract or implement abstract method

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient, abstractmethoderror

I am trying to set up an Elasticsearch high level rest client to connect with an already set up ES cluster via Http Host setup and regular credential authentication. I am setting this up to ingest data from my local system to the central cluster, periodically. My code snippet for that looks something like the following :

```
    final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
    RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, "https"))
        .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {
            @Override
            public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
            }
        });
```

Howver, I seem to be facing the Error : "Class anonymous class derived from HttpClientConfigCallback() must be declared abstract or implement abstract method customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder) in HttpClientConfigCallback" and also an error on the @Override method following it, stating "Method does not override method from it's superclass".

Can anyone tell me how should I implement that abstract method or do I need to import anything else?

Comment: Suggestion: throw away all the stuff that doesnt contribute to THIS question. Meaning: dong give us all that builder code and whatnot. Just a small tiny example that tries to instantiate that anonymous inner class. I would be guessing that something about the method signature is wrong, thus your code isnt actually overriding anything, thus your class there doesnt implement the required method, thus the compile error

Comment: That is just to show how I am creating the Rest client. If someone has worked on this, definitely he/she will know what I am trying to do here. Even Elastic website shows only this code snippet only, nothing else

Comment: You want to make it as simple as possible for people to help you with your problem. Anything that doesnt contribute to your problem ... is better left out. You see, that is even for your **own** debugging. When I run into source code that doesnt compile, I also step back and try to peel it like an onion, to get to the most minimal number of lines that give the problem. And that is what this community asks any user to do, too: [mcve].

Comment: Ok, have edited it now.